# What happens when print a numeric_limits<float>::infinity() with "%x"?

Tags: c++, hex, std, type-conversion

when I want to print the hex of numeric_limits::infinity(), something happens like this (Windows 8, Visual Studio 2013):

```
float a = numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
cout <<a << endl;
printf("%x\n", *(unsigned int*)&a);
float b;
memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(a));
cout << b << endl;
printf("%x,%x\n",1025,*(unsigned int *)&b);
```

the result (sorry i'm newbie so that can't post images):

1.#INF

7f800000

1.#INF

401,7f800000

it seems 0x7f800000 represents a infinity. However, when I change

```
printf("%x,%x\n",1025,*(unsigned int *)&b);
```

into this:

```
printf("%x,%x\n",1025.0,*(unsigned int *)&b);
```

the hex of b is changed:

1.#INF

7f800000

1.#INF

0,40900400

(I know "%x" cannot output a float type.)

and when I use different float number before b, the hex of b shows different result. What happens?

by the way, what exactly determines a variable's data type in memory?

Comment: See [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) for how floating point numbers are often encoded. (The question of viewing the bit patterns through an integer 'view' is separate, and probably answered elsewhere.)

Comment: `numeric_limits<float>::infinity();` just produces an overlown `float` value. Which one exactly depends on the used stdlib. In MSVC it is defined as `(float)1e+300 * 1e+300` with the comment `// _HUGE_ENUF*_HUGE_ENUF must overflow`

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%x,%x\n",1025.0,*(unsigned int *)&b);
```

That line invokes undefined behavior because you are trying to print a `double` as an integer. Invoking undefined behavior produces unpredictable results. Printing nonsense is one possible way of being unpredictable.

(My guess is that you are compiling the program as a 32-bit program on x86. The size of a `double` is not the same as the size of an `int`, so this causes the remainder of the argument list to be misread. Other processors and calling conventions will produce in different garbage results.)